# Elasticsearch: Merge result of aggregation by bucket key

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I've indexed entities in Elasticsearch, which occur in my documents. The mapping for the entities looks like the following:

```
"Entities": {
        "properties": {
          "EntFrequency": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "EntId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "EntType": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "english",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "Entname": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "english",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
 [...]
```

Furthermore, I use this aggregation query to determine the most-occurring entities:

```
GET cable/document/_search
{
  "size" :0,
  "query": { 
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs" : { 
      "entities_agg" : { 
          "terms" : { 
            "field" : "Entities.EntId"              
            }
          }
      }
   }
}

Response

"buckets": [
    {
      "key": 323644,
      "doc_count": 231038
    },
[...]
```

However, some of those entity mentions refer to the same entity e.g. "USA" and "United States" and I do know their ids. **How do I merge the buckets and the counts of these duplicates in ES?**

I cannot use a client-side solution since there are too many entities and retrieving all of them and merging would be probably too slow for my application. The knowledge about duplicates is acquired through runtime. Thus, I cannot use this knowledge for the initial creation of my ES index.

Thanks for your help and comments!

Comment: normalize the value while inserting into ES . Meaning convert "USA" to "United States"  or vice versa

Comment: Well, as I wrote, the knowledge that "USA" and "United States" refers to the same entity is acquired through runtime of my application. That is when the index is already created and a re-creation of the index after each "merge" operation by the user is not feasible.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end?